My pagefooter with setting - print only last page - apears on more pages
I've made a invoice report based on a dataset from AL (Business Central). It contains 2 dataitems - head and line information. NB: the head contains the totals of the invoice.
The totals of the invoice are placed in the pagefooter of the report - in there is marked for just show on last page. The invoice lines contain the property - can grow - true.
When i print the report with 3 pages the following occurs:

If the lines have not grown everything is fine - the pagefooter is printed only on the last page;
If the lines have grown (so for example three rows due to growth) the pagefooter is printed on the second and the last page.

I have no clue to fix this. I expected that you could use can grow in combination with correct presentation of the totals on the pagefooter only on the last page.
I hope i can receive some tips/ tricks/ advise.
kind regards
